# Avoid writing the same .loc in pandas many times

Tags: python, pandas

Here's some code that illustrates my problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0, 9, 10),
                   'col2': np.random.randint(0, 9, 10),
                   'col3': np.random.randint(0, 9, 10)})

# Can this be written in a better way?
df.loc[df['col1'] > df['col2'], 'col3'] = (df.loc[df['col1'] > df['col2'], 'col2'] +
                                           df.loc[df['col1'] > df['col2'], 'col3'])
```

Basically, there is a case where I want to subset a dataframe with a somewhat long condition and replace values with an expression based on other columns. This is how I end up writing it, but I think there's probably a better way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a `mask`, and in this specific sum operation you can simplify with `+=` a bit like:

```
mask = df['col1'] > df['col2']
df.loc[mask, 'col3'] += df.loc[mask, 'col2']
```

If you want to create a subset, you could try something like:

```
mask = df['col1']>df['col2']
tmp_df = df.loc[mask, ['col2', 'col3']]
# here you could do whatever on tmp_df without modifying df like
tmp_df *= 2 # just as example
# them assign the value back to df only for the rows and columns you want
df.loc[mask, 'col3'] = tmp_df.sum(axis=1)
```

but you still need the `mask` in the `loc` when assigning the value in 'col3'. It may be easier to read for the operation on the right side of the equation

Comment: masks are great as well! :) +1

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer and @Terry's filled some gaps that I had in my knowledge  of .loc

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have duplicate indexes, you can try:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] > df['col2'], 'col3'] = df['col2'] +  df['col3']
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my case, honestly I didn't understand that this is how it works for .loc and thought I had to type it out each time

Comment: @Alexvonrass Even some previous versions always need to type the .loc command. Now you just need to be careful with the index value :)